# Fine calcium carbonate powder from eggshells

Tags: experimental-chemistry

My goal is to create a very fine calcium carbonate powder using only common materials and ingredients, no specialized chemicals, equipment or tools. I start by placing an egg in vinegar, and letting that sit until the eggshell is gone. Assuming there's not too much acetic acid, this should give me calcium acetate and water, right?

Next, I bake some baking soda at 200F for an hour or two, hopefully this produces sodium carbonate, which is more water-soluble than sodium bicarbonate. I dissolve this in water until it is saturated. (my goal here is to ensure that any powder produced is the target material, without precise measurements, so we combine two clear liquids, rather than adding a powder into a clear liquid)

Finally, I add the dissolved sodium carbonate to the calcium acetate solution until it looks like nothing is happening anymore, which should precipitate ~pure calcium carbonate, right?

It seems that calcium carbonate takes different forms, and I'd like to produce the variety that has certain spectral qualities (calcite?). Namely, reflects the majority of the solar spectrum (.3-2.5 μm) and emits in the atmospheric window spectrum (8–13 μm). Will this process work?

Comment: Please edit to explain what “reflects the solar spectrum and emits in the atmospheric window spectrum” mean.

Comment: @EdV I believe I'm trying to make micro/nano calcite crystals, as opposed to the other CaCO3 polymorphs like vaterite or aragonite. For the spectral properties, see line 154 of https://tinyurl.com/caco3-paint. So my main question is about the chemical composition of what I'm trying to produce, just to double check my logic, and the secondary question is about the specific variety of calcium carbonate produced, which might belong in its own question.

Comment: What are you looking for ? Adding a solution of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ to a solution of calcium acetate will produce a precipitate of $\ce{CaCO3}$.  Why do you want to know the crystallization system of CaCO3 ? This question was simply ignored in Lim's article. It does not seem to have any interest, as the used CaCO3 is a microcrystalline powder.

Comment: Ah, then I agree with @Maurice that your prep of calcium carbonate is feasible. Like most experimental procedures, it is subject to the old Yogi Berra saying: “In theory, theory and practice are the same; in practice, they ain’t”. So, good luck!

Comment: @Maurice I would like to know the polymorph because I believe calcite has the spectral properties I'm looking for (based on other sources)

Comment: @Reese, it will be difficult to know if the structure of the $\ce{CaCO3}$ precipitate is calcite or aragonite.